# How do I remove siblings from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this working code:

```
  a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
```

I need to also remove this child's previous sibling, i.e. the element that comes before it.

How do I update this? Does MDN have documentation on it?

Comment: `a.parentNode.removeChild( a.previousSibling );`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.previousSibling

Comment: thank you , do people have these things memorized or do you reference it somewhere, getting tired of googling everything and finding it on random web-sites.  thanks again

Comment: Btw are you sure that the previous node is an element node? It could be a text node...

Comment: For future reference: [The DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference), more specifically, [the `Node` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node).

Comment: i know I need a good dom viewer for IE

Comment: @Chris Well, the spec for the *Node* interface is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247

Comment: Anyone going to post the answer?

Comment: @Chris to a certain extent it is memorisation, but it is really about learning the vocabulary. In your question you said `this child's previous sibling`, and the child is `a` so the answer was `a.previousSibling`. That tells me that you've mostly memorised it already.

Comment: True...just talk to the javascript :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution which takes into account that the previous sibling might not be an element node:

```
var previous = a.previousSibling;

// iterate until we find an element node or there is no previous sibling
while(previous && previous.nodeType !== 1) {
    previous = previous.previousSibling;
}

// if there is a sibling, remove it
if(previous) {
    previous.parentNode.removeChild(previous);
}
```

**Reference:** [`Node.previousSibling` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.previousSibling)

You could easily create a function which gives you the previous element node.

I will repeat my comment here:

You can find a [reference of all DOM interfaces at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference), in particular, the [`Node` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node).

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but in case someone finds it, nowadays browser support for `Element.remove()` is pretty wide spread, so you can just navigate with an `elementVar = elementVar.previousSibling` or `elementVar.next(Element)Sibling` and once your elementVar reaches the element you want, hit `elementVar.remove()`. That is, no need to get the `parentNode` anymore

Comment: In regards to [flen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621141/flen)'s comment....the correct syntax is `elementVar.nextSibling(Element);`

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**
   * Removes all sibling elements after specified
   * @param {HTMLElement} currentElement
   * @private
   */
  _removeNextSiblings(currentElement) {
    while (!!currentElement.nextElementSibling) {
      currentElement.nextElementSibling.remove();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is to remove all sibling elements except for .me

```
const node = document.querySelector('.me');
const clone = node.cloneNode(true);

const parentNode = node.parentNode;
parentNode.innerHTML = '';
parentNode.append(clone);
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However, if there is animation on ".me". It would re-animate every time.